# Views Formatter Problem

Tags: views, entities

How do I control what gets displayed for Views Formatting?  I mean, Something is wrong here.  I have a View set up to show Fields of a Content Type, when I click on the `Content: Body` Field it shows Formatting Options, Default, Plain Text, Trimmed, Summary or Trimmed.  I just want to output the Body field of a content type AS HTML.  What the hell is wrong this.  I select "Default" View, but I get absolute NOTHING returned.  When I select Plain Text, I just get the text returned, no HTML.

What do I need to do so that the default option in Views actually outputs something?  Preferrably outputs it in the default format, which is HTML.

Comment: You should get HTML by default. Have you checked the other settings for this field?

Comment: @Alex - Yes, I'ved checked the other settings.  I am using the default `Body` Field for the Content Type that gets automatically generated by default when creating a Content Type in `Structure -> Content Types -> Add Content Type`.  I have CKEditor Module installed and in each actual Content, I have it set on FULL HTML, but it returns NOTHING!  No text or anything when the View Format is set to `Default` for this.  But when I switch the View Formatter to `Plain Text` on this field, it than works, but only shows text.  What other options should I be looking at?

Comment: When I output the Content as `Content` instead of Field, it shows nothing also for the `Content: Body` area.  WEIRD!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have the Display Suite Module installed in Drupal 7.25. I went to `Admin -> Configuration -> Content Authoring -> Text Formats` and Disabled the Display Suite Text format, Cleared the Cache, and now all of my Body: Content is showing as HTML in my Views as it should!

Hope this helps someone! There is a problem with the Display Suite Code Text Format that is causing the Default formatter and any other displays (even Content) to NOT Show anything!